# A question in general topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $x$ be a point in $X$ and let $U$ be an open subset of $X$. Then, is it true that $x\in U$ if and only if $U\cap \overline{\{x\}}\ne \emptyset$? If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Based on the definition of a closure here: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Closure_of_a_set, the closure of $\{ x \}$ must contain $x$...

So your intersection would at least have $x$ in it if $x \in U$.

Comment: Oh right. Thank you. I didn’t note that.✋

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in U$ then clearly, as we always have $x \in \overline{\{x\}}$, we get $x \in \overline{\{x\}} \cap U$.

OTOH, if some $y \in  \overline{\{x\}} \cap U$, $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ and as $y \in \overline{\{x\}}$, $U \cap \{x\} \neq \emptyset$, which happens iff $x \in U$.

So yes.